# Java Server faces - setters not being called

Tags: java, jsf, setter

I'm currently learning JSF and are having some problems with setters not being called. I'm writing a very simple program, it consists of an .XHTML file and a .java class. The point of the program is to choose a day, month and year and then display your choice. As i understand JSF the following should call the underlying setter and save the appropriate value in the appropriate field:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value ="#{bean.selectedDay}" onchange = "submit()"> 
    <f:selectItems value ="#{bean.days}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

In this example the field "selectedDay" is never assigned any value. I would really like to understand why this is happening. I'm currently running Windows 8 and using Eclipse with Glassfish. Full code can be seen below.
Thank you for your time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
<title>kalenderting</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
<h:form>
<h:selectOneMenu value ="#{bean.selectedDay}" onchange = "submit()"> 
    <f:selectItems value ="#{opg2.days}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu> 

<h:selectOneMenu value ="#{bean.selectedMonth}" onchange = "submit()" >
    <f:selectItems value ="#{bean.months}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<br/>
#{bean.date}
</h:form>
</h:body>
```

the bean:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped 
public class Bean implements Serializable {


private List<Integer> days;
private List<String> months;
private List<Integer> years;
private int selectedDay ;
private String selectedMonth;


public Bean()
{   
    months = new ArrayList<String>();
    years = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    days = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    days.add(1);
    days.add(2);

    months.add("januar");
    months.add("februar");

    for( int i = 1990; i<=2020; i++)
    {
        years.add(i);
    }       
}

public List<Integer> getDays() {

    return days;
}

public void setDays(List<Integer> days) {
    this.days = days;
}

public List<String> getMonths() {
    return months;
}

public void setMonths(List<String> months) {
    this.months = months;
}

public List<Integer> getYears() {
    return years;
}

public void setYears(List<Integer> years) {
    this.years = years;
}

public int getSelectedDay() {
    return selectedDay;
}

public void setSelectedDay(int selectedDay) {
    this.selectedDay = selectedDay;
}

public String getSelectedMonth() {
    return selectedMonth;
}

public void setSelectedMonth(String selectedMonth) {
    this.selectedMonth = selectedMonth;
}

public String getDate()
{
    return selectedDay + ". " + selectedMonth;
}
```

Comment: Run the debugger. Is the bean constructor hit? Read the server logs. Aren't there any errors/warnings? As to the concrete use case, you may find this blog also helpful: [composite component with multiple input fields](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html)

Comment: would you show your faces-config.xml file?

Comment: in you'r .XTHML file, i can see "opg2.days". What it is. I think replace this line <f:selectItems value ="#{opg2.days}"/> with <f:selectItems value ="#{bean.days}"/>. and also check your Arraylist and variable type both are must be same type.